# Very strange issue trying to get rails to work on OS X 10.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am encountering a very weird issue trying to get rails working on my system.   Every time I try to run rails after installing it says I need to install.  If someone could point me in the right path or give me some tips on how to further troubleshoot it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much

$ rails
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

```
$ sudo gem install rails
Fetching: rails-4.0.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-4.0.2
Parsing documentation for rails-4.0.2
Installing ri documentation for rails-4.0.2
Done installing documentation for rails after 436 seconds
1 gem installed

$ which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails


$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.0.2)
actionpack (4.0.2)
activemodel (4.0.2)
activerecord (4.0.2)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activesupport (4.0.2)
arel (4.0.1)
atomic (1.1.14)
bigdecimal (1.2.3)
builder (3.1.4)
bundler (1.5.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.9)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.8.4)
polyglot (0.3.3)
psych (2.0.2)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
**rails (4.0.2)**
railties (4.0.2)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
sprockets (2.10.1)
sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
test-unit (2.1.0.0)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.38)

$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

Comment: Have you checked that `/usr/local/bin/` is in your path?

Comment: you can use `rvm` or `rbenv` to install ruby+rails. one of the positive sides is that it avoids having to use `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

Rails is here:

```
$ which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails
```

But calling rails doesn't work:

```
$ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system.
```

That means bash doesn't have its path in your `PATH` variable.

To add it (assuming you're on a mac), issue

```
$ echo 'export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then reload with

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

And see if it recognizes the `rails` command then.

Comment: That was already set up.

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: